# MultipartFile array not sending to spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I send a post request to my spring controller using JS, but am not able to receive a multipartFile array all i get is null. I send 3 separate parameters which are shown below. (artwork,tracks and metadata)

```
    formData.append("artwork", $scope.image[0]);
    formData.append("tracks", $scope.files);
    formData.append("metadata",JSON.stringify(contentData));


    // $http.post('/review/' + $scope.objectID, formData).then("Successfully got objects !", "Successfully got objects !");
    $http({
    url: '/review/'+ $scope.objectID,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': undefined},
    data: formData,
    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetterFunction) {
      return data;
    }
  }).
```

I do receive metadata ( which is a String) and artwork (which is a single MultiPartFile) from the parameters but null for tracks (Array MultiPartFile).

Here my Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/review/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public void formHandler(
    @PathVariable("id") String id,
    @RequestPart("artwork") MultipartFile artwork,
    @RequestPart("tracks") MultipartFile[] tracks, 
    @RequestPart("metadata") String object) {


   // SubmissionsRequestObject subObject = getSubObject(object, artwork, tracks);
   // System.out.println(subObject.getAlbumname());
    System.out.println(object);
    System.out.println("-----");
   System.out.println(tracks.length);
   System.out.println(tracks);
   System.out.println("-----");
   for (MultipartFile t : tracks){
        System.out.println("count");
   }
   System.out.println(artwork.getOriginalFilename());
   // new SRP(subObject);



}
```

Comment: Did you check the developers console and see if the files are sent OR debugged to see if the $scope.files has the files?

Comment: Hi yes i did output result on the console and it has files... $scope.file = [File, File, File, File, File, File, File] (Correct output) just don't receive anything at the controller end @RossiRobinsion

Comment: I think what you have to do is instead of passing the array of files, you can append them in FormData individually. Since your artwork file is working but tracks.

Comment: the amount of files uploaded isnt fixed and can vary. so passing individually will be impossible

Answer (score 3):

You can try this when you append `$scope.files` to `formData`;)

```
for (var file in $scope.files) {
    formData.append("tracks", file);
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks for ur help         for (var x = 0; x < $scope.files.length; x++) {
            formData.append("tracks", $scope.files[x]);
            console.log($scope.files[x]);
        }

Comment: @D.Asare Does `for-in` really not work? It's so weird.:-(

Comment: it doesn't seem to, after doing some checks it seems like the var changes the file into an integer and only stores the position of the file in the array rather than the file itself.